# How do I pass parameters through "use" method in CompoundJS?

Tags: node.js, controller, express, parameters, compoundjs

I am using CompoundJS (an MVC for Express / NodeJS). To share code between controllers [the Doc says](http://compoundjs.com/man/controller.3.html#FLOW-CONTROL-METHODS) that on `controller1.js` I can share a method by using `publish` method:

```
/***controller1.js***/
function sharedFunction () {...}
publish('sharedFunction', sharedFunction); //Sharing...
```

And in the `controller2.js` I can access it by `load`ing it and trying the `use` method:

```
/***controller2.js***/
load('controller1'); //  _controller siffix must be omitted
use('sharedFunction')
```

**PROBLEM**

This works great, however, I have a `sharedFunction`that has params:

```
/***controller1.js***/
function sharedFunction (param1, param2) {...}
publish('sharedFunction', sharedFunction); //Sharing...
```

I have been reading the Docs, however I can't find how, or the syntax, to add this params on my `use`method on `controller1.js`. **Where do I send these params?**:

```
/***controller2.js***/
load('controller1'); //  _controller siffix must be omitted
use('sharedFunction(params here?)', {params here?}) //where do I send the params?
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I've done:

```
var sharedFunction = use('sharedFunction');

sharedFunction(param1, param2);
```